# How can I retrieve a Page ID to adhere to new requirements of API 3.2?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook Graph API ugprade tool for going to 3.2 seems to say that we can no longer request a list of posts using a Page Name, ie GET {page-name-id}/posts.

Of course, I can just do a very simple GET on the page name and I will retrieve the ID as one of two arguments - and many similar questions on here have been answered in this way - but isn't this still accessing an endpoint we're not supposed to? Indeed when I changed my code to do this, I still received a warning from the upgrade tool.

It's quite unclearly worded as to what is deprecated and/or will stop working.

[image: Warning from Facebook]

Comment: Using the page username still seems to work fine in v3.2, tested in Graph API Explorer. I can’t find anything about this in the changelogs either.

Comment: Thanks @04FS - Yeah I ran it through the explorer as well, and I'm actually confident that it works too, but... these warnings seem to be saying it should be migrated, right? Or am I misreading.

Comment: Is there any more info hidden behind the “(i) Change” on the right maybe?

Comment: No, you'd think so! But it's just an icon. Here's the link, if you have any example apps to test it on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/api_versioning/